# Adding a single Console.WriteLine() outside a loop changes a loop's timings - why?

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            for (int trial = 0; trial < 4; ++trial)
            {
                sw.Restart();
                loop1();
                Console.WriteLine("loop1() took " + sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();
                loop2();
                Console.WriteLine("loop2() took " + sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();
                loop3();
                Console.WriteLine("loop3() took " + sw.Elapsed);

                // Console.WriteLine(); // <-- Uncomment this and the timings change a LOT!
            }
        }

        static void loop1()
        {
            bool done = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000 && !done; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100000 && !done; ++j)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
                    {
                        if (i == 9900)
                        {
                            done = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void loop2()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100000; ++j)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
                    {
                        if (i == 9900)
                        {
                            goto exit;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        exit: return;
        }

        static void loop3()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100000; ++j)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
                    {
                        if (i == 9900)
                        {
                            k = 2;
                            j = 100000;
                            i = 100000;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile and run a RELEASE x86 build of this on Windows 7 x64 using Visual Studio 2010, I get the following timings (running on Intel Core i7)

```
loop1() took 00:00:01.7935267
loop2() took 00:00:01.4747297
loop3() took 00:00:05.6677592
loop1() took 00:00:01.7654008
loop2() took 00:00:01.4818888
loop3() took 00:00:05.7656440
loop1() took 00:00:01.7990239
loop2() took 00:00:01.5019258
loop3() took 00:00:05.7979425
loop1() took 00:00:01.8356245
loop2() took 00:00:01.5688070
loop3() took 00:00:05.7238753
```

That in itself is odd - why would loop3() be so much slower than the other loops?
Anyway, I then uncomment the indicated line (the Console.WriteLine()), and my timings become:

```
loop1() took 00:00:01.8229538
loop2() took 00:00:07.8174210
loop3() took 00:00:01.4879274

loop1() took 00:00:01.7691919
loop2() took 00:00:07.4781999
loop3() took 00:00:01.4810248

loop1() took 00:00:01.7749845
loop2() took 00:00:07.5304738
loop3() took 00:00:01.4634904

loop1() took 00:00:01.7521282
loop2() took 00:00:07.6325186
loop3() took 00:00:01.4663219
```

Now loop2() is far slower, and loop3() far quicker. I find this most curious...

So I have two questions:

1. Can anyone else reproduce this, and
2. If so, can anyone explain it?

[EDIT] I should add that I can verify these timings with a stopwatch, and I am running the test program from the command-line (so we can rule out Visual Studio interfering with it).

ADDENDUM:

I modified the program as follows to exclude the possibility that the JITTER is optimizing out the loops:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test());
        }

        static string test()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            int total = 0;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int trial = 0; trial < 2; ++trial)
            {
                sw.Restart();
                total += loop1();
                builder.AppendLine("loop1() took " + sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();
                total += loop2();
                builder.AppendLine("loop2() took " + sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();
                total += loop3();
                builder.AppendLine("loop3() took " + sw.Elapsed);
                //builder.AppendLine(); // Uncommenting this line makes a big difference!
            }

            builder.AppendLine(total.ToString());

            return builder.ToString();
        }

        static int loop1()
        {
            bool done = false;
            int total = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000 && !done; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100000 && !done; ++j)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
                    {
                        if (i == 9900)
                        {
                            done = true;
                            break;
                        }

                        ++total;
                    }
                }
            }

            return total;
        }

        static int loop2()
        {
            int total = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100000; ++j)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
                    {
                        if (i == 9900)
                        {
                            goto exit;
                        }

                        ++total;
                    }
                }
            }

        exit: return total;
        }

        static int loop3()
        {
            int total = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100000; ++j)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
                    {
                        if (i == 9900)
                        {
                            k = 2;
                            j = 100000;
                            i = 100000;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ++total;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return total;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my results are as follows:

builder.AppendLine() commented out:

```
loop1() took 00:00:06.6509471
loop2() took 00:00:06.7322771
loop3() took 00:00:01.5361389
loop1() took 00:00:06.5746730
loop2() took 00:00:06.7051531
loop3() took 00:00:01.5027345
-1004901888
```

builder.AppendLine() not commented out:

```
loop1() took 00:00:06.9444200
loop2() took 00:00:02.8960563
loop3() took 00:00:01.4759535

loop1() took 00:00:06.9036553
loop2() took 00:00:03.1514154
loop3() took 00:00:01.4764172

-1004901888
```

Note the difference in the loop2() timing when I do that. Does not compute!

Comment: Stopwatch is not reliable, at least in some cases: http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.com/2008/10/beware-of-stopwatch.html

Comment: No and no. Are you running without debugging? (Why a goto? Why not just a return?)

Comment: Stopwatch is completely reliable in this case though because (1) it's running on a single thread and (2) the processor is not lowering its clock speed. Also, I can time it with a stopwatch, or just by counting to myself. The differences in time are that great!

Comment: @Thomas: I'm not running under the debugger (in fact I'm running from the command line). There's a goto there because that's what I was testing. So what timings do you get for both cases?

Comment: Around 1.6 for loop2 & loop3, 1.9 for loop1.

Comment: No and no also. loop1() took 00:00:01.6828958
loop2() took 00:00:01.7620809
loop3() took 00:00:01.3998184, although I was compiling x86 on VS2012/Win7 x64

Comment: @Thomas: And you compiled it as x86 release, and are running on Windows 7 x64? I'm going to ask some colleagues to try this. It's very weird.

Comment: We need to know your OS, bitness and .NET version. All your "loop" functions have no side-effects and can be optimized out entirely. Depending on the JIT version this might behave *very* differently.

Comment: For example, in loop1 and loop3, the k-loop is clearly redundant. In loop3 it is harder to detect that. Probably the JIT is not smart enough for that. That would explain the difference in duration.

Comment: @usr: It's .Net 4 (the default for VS2010). I can imagine the Jitter eliminating some code - but it seems very strange that it would behave so differently when a console.writeline() is used outside the loops...

Comment: Tried both x86 and AnyCPU, running on Windows 7 x64 SP1.

Comment: This is not happening on a colleague's PC. I'm mystified why it's doing it on mine. :)

Comment: On my machine (Windows 7 x86, compiled on Release mode .Net 4.0), loop 2 is indeed faster when `Console...` is uncommented (2.99 vs 3.37)

Comment: Have we tried decompiling the assembly yet?

Comment: The loops can still be optimized out entirely as all side-effects are local. Try adding to a static variable in the innermost loop the value (i + j + k). That will change the timings but it will rule out the loops being (partially) removed.

Comment: Please see my addendum to the OP - I added code to prevent it being optimised out. I now get a different weird result...

Comment: Yes I saw your addendum. It doesn't work because all side-effects are to local variables. The compiler can throw everything out.

Comment: @usr: No, I'm returning the value from each loop, adding them all up and printing out the result. The compiler sure as hell can't optimise that away! Did you misread my code perhaps?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I did misread it indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce that exactly. In addition though, I can make the variance go away like this:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        for (int trial = 0; trial < 4; ++trial)
        {
            sw.Restart();
            Interlocked.MemoryBarrier();
            loop1();
            Interlocked.MemoryBarrier();
            Console.WriteLine("loop1() took " + sw.Elapsed);

            sw.Restart();
            Interlocked.MemoryBarrier();
            loop2();
            Interlocked.MemoryBarrier();
            Console.WriteLine("loop2() took " + sw.Elapsed);

            sw.Restart();
            Interlocked.MemoryBarrier();
            loop3();
            Interlocked.MemoryBarrier();
            Console.WriteLine("loop3() took " + sw.Elapsed);

            // Console.WriteLine(); // <-- Uncomment this and the timings don't change now.
        }
    }
```

When I run with the MemoryBarriers, I get the second pattern no matter which way I run the test:

```
loop1() took ~1 sec
loop2() took ~7 secs
loop3() took ~1 sec
```

MemoryBarrier definition:

> Synchronizes memory access as follows: The processor executing the current thread cannot reorder instructions in such a way that memory accesses prior to the call to MemoryBarrier execute after memory accesses that follow the call to MemoryBarrier.

Since the IL for the loops is identical between the 2 versions, and MemoryBarrier makes the variance disappear, I think we can conclude the variance is definitely the result of an optimization on the first pattern... maybe by the JITer... maybe by the CPU... not sure there.

My environment is the same, except I am using VS2012 & .NET 4.5 RTM.

Comment: I believe MemoryBarrier will clear all the CPU caches. So perhaps the variance has to do with memory I/O that's getting cached by the CPU in some cases and not others? Hard to imagine these loop variables being backed by anything other than registers, though.

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting. It's very strange that loop2() would slow down so much... Possibly because it's not being optimised like the others (the goto confuses the optimiser perhaps?) Note that I added an addendum to my OP with code that prevents the optimiser from removing code (I think) - and that introduced a different strange effect...

Comment: We don't do much memory access here. I think this answer just scratches the surface. The real answer is to be found by looking at the x86 disassembly.